# How to grant/limit access on Images sub folders for each Customer?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following structure inside my wwwroot/images:

wwwroot

-------Images

-------------Customers

-----------------------Each costumers has his own folder name.

Each folder has an image which only the customer might have access.

The problem is: If some user types the address of other user's image, it will open.

I'm trying to restrict the access of each folder using the table Company from the data base.

I could do it on MVC 5 using location path on web config.

But how could I do it in appsettings.json on .NET Core?

Thanks guys!

OBS: If you have any other approach for this, will be welcome :D

Answer (score 1):

The Static File Middleware doesn't provide authorization checks. Any files served by it, including those under wwwroot, are publicly accessible. To serve files based on authorization, you could refer [Static file authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2#static-file-authorization).

For another option, you may consider implement a custom middleware check the identity like

```
app.Map("/specificpath", subApp => {
    subApp.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
        }
        else if(context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/specificpath/User1") && context.User.Identity.Name != "User1")
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
        }
    });
});

app.UseStaticFiles();
```